# Neo4j - Order a list which is part of intermediate result

Tags: sorting, collections, neo4j, subquery, cypher

I'm using the [movies2](https://data.neo4j.com/advanced-cypher/movies2.csv) database available as part of Query Tuning Exercises in the Neo4j Desktop.
I want to return a table with titles of movies where titles that have been used more than once, with the no. of times that title has been used, and a sorted list of their release years. The table itself should have the movies with higher no. of title reuse at the top.

What is the most efficient way to frame a Cypher query that can accomplish the above?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a one (probably convoluted) query that accomplishes the requisite output.

```
CALL {
    CALL {
        MATCH (m:Movie)
        WITH collect(DISTINCT m.title) AS mTitles
        UNWIND mTitles AS mt
        MATCH (m:Movie)
        WHERE m.title = mt
        WITH mt, count(*) AS numT, collect(m.releaseYear) AS relYr
        WHERE numT > 1
        RETURN mt, numT, relYr}
    UNWIND relYr AS yr
    RETURN mt, numT, yr
    ORDER BY yr}
RETURN mt, numT, collect(yr)
ORDER BY numT DESC
```

Here's the output, sorted by

1. releaseYear ascending,
2. num of times title used descending :

```
╒════════════════════════════════════╤══════╤════════════════╕
│"mt"                                │"numT"│"collect(yr)"   │
╞════════════════════════════════════╪══════╪════════════════╡
│"Dracula"                           │3     │[1931,1958,1992]│
├────────────────────────────────────┼──────┼────────────────┤
│"King Kong"                         │3     │[1933,1976,2005]│
├────────────────────────────────────┼──────┼────────────────┤
│"Alice in Wonderland"               │3     │[1951,1999,2010]│
├────────────────────────────────────┼──────┼────────────────┤
│"Godzilla"                          │3     │[1954,1998,2014]│
├────────────────────────────────────┼──────┼────────────────┤
│"The Three Musketeers"              │3     │[1973,1993,2011]│
├────────────────────────────────────┼──────┼────────────────┤
│"Carrie"                            │3     │[1976,2002,2013]│
├────────────────────────────────────┼──────┼────────────────┤
│"Beauty and the Beast"              │3     │[1991,2009,2014]│
├────────────────────────────────────┼──────┼────────────────┤
│"The Kid"                           │2     │[1921,2000]     │
├────────────────────────────────────┼──────┼────────────────┤
│"Metropolis"                        │2     │[1927,2001]     │
├────────────────────────────────────┼──────┼────────────────┤
│"Frankenstein"                      │2     │[1931,1994]     │
...
```